# How to check whether a string contains special characters

Tags: php, csv

I have a csv file.When it opens with character set 'UTF-8',it contains  some values like

```
Bedre Psykiatri - Landsforeningen for p?É¬•r?É¬?rende
Central de Atendimento T?Ø¬ø¬?cnico
Centro de Extens?Ø¬ø¬?o Universit?Ø¬ø¬?ria
Centro Universit?Ø¬ø¬?rio Feevale
```

Now,I have php script , which reads the above csv file.

Let me know ,how can i check whether the strings getting from the csv file is a type of above pattern ?

Comment: You can use `preg_match()` to search a template

Comment: @ThomasRollet.thanks for your reply.But let me know what should be the pattern.or is there any in built php functions ?

Comment: use this pattern preg_match("/[~`!@#$%^&*()_-+=\[\]{}\|\\:;\"\'<,>.]/", $string)

Comment: You can recognize whether a string contains UTF-8 characters; but that is something clumsy. I guess these characters are not simple "special characters" but rather characters from a different character set (like "latin-1", etc.) that you handle as UTF-8 characters or vice-versa. I suggest you make sure that everything is UTF-8 (UTF-8 without BOM): the CSV file and the PHP script handling it.

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this

```
<?php
$illegal = "#$%^&*()+=-[]';,./{}|:<>?~";
echo (false === strpbrk($YourCsvVarible, $illegal)) ? 'Allowed' : "Disallowed";
?>
```

Note :
`strpbrk(string,charlist)` it will return false when string not contain character which you passed in 2ed argument and see i have passed all character in `$illegal = "#$%^&*()+=-[]';,./{}|:<>?~";` if you need more http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpbrk.php

Comment: Could you explain how your answer addresses the problem(s) from the question? Code-only answers are not very useful, especially for further readers that stumble upon this post. Thanks!

Comment: see my updated ans and if this ans is true and worked for you then please don't forget to declare as true